# How to display multicolumn combobox in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have written the code to populate the ComboBox and also set the `BoundColumn` and `ColumnCount` values to 2.

My requirement is to display material ID and material description in a ComboBox to make it user friendly.

But when I run the UserForm it is showing only second column (i.e material name).   I also want to capture the selection and both values individually in two variables for further processing.

I am calling this macro in the *initialize* event of my UserForm.

```
Sub inittCode()

    Dim tcodelist() As String
    Dim tnamelist() As String

    'Activates master data sheet
    Worksheets("MD").Activate
    mylr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Calculate range size to initialize array
    Size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1))

    ReDim tcodelist(Size)
    ReDim tnamelist(Size)

    'fill the first array
    For X = 2 To mylr
        tcodelist(X - 1) = Cells(X, 1)
    Next X

    'Adjust Array size to remove null values
    For a = 0 To mylr - 1
        tcodelist(a) = tcodelist(a + 1)
    Next a
    ReDim Preserve tcodelist(Size - 2)

    'Fill second array
    For x1 = 2 To mylr
        tnamelist(x1 - 1) = Cells(x1, 2)
    Next x1

    'Remove null values and adjust size
    For b = 0 To mylr - 1
        tnamelist(b) = tnamelist(b + 1)
    Next b
    ReDim Preserve tnamelist(Size - 2)

    'Fill combobox with array values
    MD_initform.matselcb.ColumnCount = 1
    MD_initform.matselcb.List = tcodelist
    MD_initform.matselcb.ColumnCount = 2
    MD_initform.matselcb.List = tnamelist

End Sub
```

Comment: It's a good idea to declare *all* of your variables.  I'd suggest you add the line `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always], which will help prevent issues by "forcing" you to properly declare & refer to your variables/objects/properties, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to display multiple columns you need to pass the list of items as 2-dimensional array. First index is for rows, second for columns.

Without understanding the details of your code, do something like

```
Dim tlist() As String
ReDim tlist(Size, 2)  ' Declare 2-dimensional array for "Size" rows and 2 cols
...
tlist(X - 1, 1) = Cells(X, 1)    ' Codes
...
tlist(x1 - 1, 2) = Cells(x1, 2)  ' Names

' Fill combobox with array values
MD_initform.matselcb.ColumnCount = 2
MD_initform.matselcb.List = tlist
```

Answer (score 0):

For multi-column ComboBoxes, Excel natively displays only 1 column, the first one or the .TextColumn one if not at default -1. I have coded a workaround module with 1 simple function that allows to display all the columns using Labels to cover the Combobox display area. [Check this link](https://excel-downloads.com/resources/vba-combobox-multi-colonnes-en-userform-afficher-toutes-les-colonnes-de-litem-selectionne.1374/) and download the file. The Web text is in French (use any Web page translation extension/tool) and the VBA comments are in English.

Comment: Check here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323751/how-to-display-multicolumn-combobox-in-excel-vba